# How do i set break point on a function declaration which does not belong to any class using windbg?

Tags: c++, windbg

I want to set break point on a function which is part of a cpp code. I am new to use windbg, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What have you tried? You can set breakpoints based on name, file and line number or the address of the function, all of which should work for standalone functions as well as class members.

Comment: The question is not very specific and detailed, but I don't get the close vote.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the n00b (easy way):

1. break in to your running executable with the debugger
2. Set the source and symbol paths to your project and deliverable. check the "reload" box.
3. Open the source (.cpp) file that contains the breakpoint you want
4. In the windbg source editor, select the line you want to break on and press F9 (just like in Visual Studio)
5. in the command window type bl to list the active breakpoints. You should see the one you just set.
6. press F5 to continue until until your breakpoint is hit.